# When element receives class, change css on another element

Tags: jquery, css, animation

**Short description of what I want to accomplish:**

Show and activate a css animation on a element when another element gets a class.

**A little longer description:**

When the li-element with the ID”widget-1” gets the class ”normal-opacity”, I want that the animations in the DIV ”animation-widget-1” to start.

When the class ”normal-opacity” continues to the next li-element, ”widget-2”. I want to hide the previously animation (in this case the DIV ”animation-widget-1”) and instead show the animation that are linked with that current li-element (in this case widget-2).

At last: when the class "normal-opacity" comes back to the first li-element, "widget-1", I want that the animations restarts.

**HTML**

A section with a list and a div containing hidden animations.

```
<section id="widget-section">
    <div class="function-content">
        <ul class="function-list">
            <li class="normal-opacity" id="widget-1">
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="widget-2">
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="widget-3">
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="widget-4">
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="animations">
        <div class="animated bounceoutdown" id="animation-widget-1">
<i class="material-icons md-48 animated bounceindown">smartphone</i>
<i class="material-icons md-48 animated bounceindown">email</i>
<i class="material-icons md-48 animated bounceindown">chat_bubble_outline</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JQUERY**

The class ”normal-opacity” jumps down to the next li element in the list ”function-list”

```
$(function () {
    var lis = $("#widget-section .function-list> li"),
        currentHighlight = 0;
    N = 6; //interval in seconds
    setInterval(function () {
        currentHighlight = (currentHighlight + 1) % lis.length;
        lis.removeClass('normal_opacity').eq(currentHighlight).addClass('normal_opacity');
    }, N * 1000);
});
```

**CSS**

```
/*MAKES LI ELEMENT HAVE OPACITY 0.5*/

.function-list li {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.function-list .normal-opacity {
    opacity: 1;
}


/*HIDES THE ANIMATION*/

.animations {
    visibility: hidden;
}


/*DECIDE WHEN ANIMATIONS WILL START*/

#animation-widget-1 {
            animation-delay: 5s;
        }
#animation-widget-1 i:first-child {
            animation-delay: 1s;
        }
#animation-widget-1 i:nth-child(2) {
            animation-delay: 1.3s;
        }
#animation-widget-1 i:last-child {
            animation-delay: 1.6s;
        }
```

I hope this question not are TO weird and that my description is fairly good.

GIF of list-animation: [Link to Giphy](http://gph.is/2o3L091)

Please comment on solutions/tips and trix to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Like so, you just have to chain a class onto the li;

```css
.function-list li.normal-opacity div {
  /* code you want to activate goes here */
}
```

This way, anything you put inside of the included code snippet will be applied to the div. If you want to start the animation, you probably just have to add the necessary `animation` property for what you want to do.